# Is there any way to unit test a function that return user model after FirebaseAuth signup with email

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-test

Currently, I am working on improving my testing skills. So I tried to test a function that creates a new user with email and password and returns UserModel with UID of the user and the email. But I stuck in the point where how I test this. I tried using the mokito but it does not pass the test because UID returns null. Following is the function that I want to test.

```
 Future<dynamic> createNewAdmin({
    @required email,
    @required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User signedUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      adminModel = AdminModel(
        adminEmail: email,
        adminUID: signedUser.uid,
      );
      print(adminModel);
      return adminModel;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        return 'weak_password';
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        return 'email-already-in-use';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

This is the test I wrote. But this is incomplete can someone tell me I test that the return type matches with expected output

```
    test('when new admin signed up succesfully Then return true', () async {
      when(mockFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: "test@gmail.com", password: "12345678"))
          .thenAnswer((_) => Future<MockAuthResult>.value());

      expect(
          await adminRepository.createNewAdmin(
            email: 'test@gmail.com',
            password: '12345678',
          ),
          AdminModel(adminEmail: "test@gmail.com", adminUID: ?));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass FirebaseAuth as a dependency in order to mock it.

```
Future<dynamic> createNewAdmin({
    @required email,
    @required String password,
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth
  }) async {
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User signedUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      adminModel = AdminModel(
        adminEmail: email,
        adminUID: signedUser.uid,
      );
      print(adminModel);
      return adminModel;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        return 'weak_password';
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        return 'email-already-in-use';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Then in the test you create the mocked instance

```
class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth {}
```

And finally you pass the instance and you can call the when method.

```
test('when new admin signed up succesfully Then return true', () async {
      when(mockFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: "test@gmail.com", password: "12345678"))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => [value you want to return]);

      expect(
          await adminRepository.createNewAdmin(
            email: 'test@gmail.com',
            password: '12345678',
            firebaseAuth: mockFirebaseAuth,
          ),
          AdminModel(adminEmail: "test@gmail.com", adminUID: ?));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I cannot Implement it because it says `The return type 'AdminModel' isn't a 'Future<UserCredential>', as required by the closure's context.`

Comment: you need another when clause  for method firebaseAuth.currentUser